# Android: changing activity language

Tags: android, localization

I have a problem with changing all text in one activity of my application... i am using this code to change language:

```
else if (LANGUAGE.equals("Russian"))
        {
            Resources res = this.getResources();
            // Change locale settings in the app.
            DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
            android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
            conf.locale = new Locale("ru-rRU");
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
}
```

in AndroidManifest i have added this string:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.vladimir.expert_suise.ThirdScreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_third_screen" 
        android:configChanges="locale">
    </activity>
```

and when i launch my app on my phone, language is not changed =(
here is screenshoot - [image: screen where i need to change language]

so what is wrong with my code?(

P.S i have also created values-ru-rRU folder and inserted there translated string.xml file

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ru-RU` not ru-rRU or am I wrong?

Comment: @codeMagic do you mean code, or folder name?

Comment: Both. I actually thought I saw somewhere you could just use `"re"` for the code and values-ru for the folder name. Does it work in other Activities or none?

Comment: @codeMagic actually when i added ru-rRU my application had been translated all, but it because my phone has Russian locale... but i don't need to translate my app with build in phone locale, i want to translate it separatly from phone locale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change values-ru-rRU to values-ru.

You can use this method to get resource

```
public Resources getCustomResource(String lang){
        Locale locale = new Locale(lang); 
        Resources standardResources = activity.getResources();
        AssetManager assets = standardResources.getAssets();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = standardResources.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration config = new Configuration(standardResources.getConfiguration());
        config.locale = locale;
        Resources res = new Resources(assets, metrics, config);
        return res;
    }
```

You can use it in your code like this

```
else if (LANGUAGE.equals("Russian"))
    {
        Resources res = getCustomResource("ru");
```

}

hope this help you.

Comment: as i understand i only need to ad this code and nothing else?

Comment: I use this method in my app for Arabic Language. I make `values-ar` folder and use method `getCustomResource("ar");`. Note: I edit my answer I use "ru", try it.

Answer (score 2):

To set language of one activity only irrespective of **Application** language (locale), below code can be used

```
public override fun attachBaseContext(context: Context) {
    // pass desired language
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(context, "hi"));
}
```

**LocaleHelper.java**

```
public class LocaleHelper {

public static Context onAttach(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
    return setLocale(context, defaultLanguage);
}

public static Context setLocale(Context context, String language) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return updateResources(context, language);
    }

    return updateResourcesLegacy(context, language);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    configuration.setLocale(locale);

    return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Resources resources = context.getResources();

    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    configuration.locale = locale;

    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

    return context;
}

}
```